# Writing to stream without file path

Tags: c#, .net, stream

I have legacy class that writes some results to a file using `StreamWriter`, created with constructor that accepts `FileStream`, which is previously created by giving it's constructor a file path:

```
        using (FileStream fs = File.Open(outputFilePath, FileMode.Create))
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
        {
            MyFileWriter.WriteToFile(someData, sw);
        }
```

By the way, stated code is used in WCF service.
Now, I have new requirement where I have to save file to a client file system and I have constraint that I can only send byte[] to client. I would like to make minimal changes to existing code to support this, so is there, for example, some kind of stream which I can create wihtout the need to specify the file path in it's constructor? Later I would convert this stream to `byte[]`.
 I'm open to any other idea you might have, as well.

Comment: Have you considered using a memory stream?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use MemoryStream,

```
    byte[] result;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ms))
    {
        MyFileWriter.WriteToFile(someData, sw);
        result = ms.ToArray();
    }

    // use the result byte[]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `MemoryStream`.

```
using (MemoryStream ms =  new MemoryStream())
{
  using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ms))
   {
     MyFileWriter.WriteToFile(someData, sw);
   }
}
```